# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in admin.php on line 219

Tags: php, mysqli, fatal-error

I've searched a lot of basically the same questions on SO which haven't seemed to help. Been a while since i've touched php so i'm guessing there's a simple solution but really can't figure it out.

config.php: (included into admin.php)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($mHost, $mUser, $mPass, $db);
```

admin.php:

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('', '$_POST[name]')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sqlQuery);
```

var_dump($result) returns:

> NULL

and gives error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in

Comment: Have you made any attempt at debugging?

Comment: Check your database connection.  Are you sure you have the right values for $mHost, $mUser, etc.?

Comment: You have a lot of code having an error on line 219. It seems $mysqli is not a mysqli object anymore. Maybe there is code before that where $mysqli is changed somehow.

Comment: Sidenote: You may want to change `$_POST[name]` to `$_POST['name']` however using such a method leaves you open to SQL injection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're wrong... OK: `"{$_POST['name']}"` `"$_POST[name]"` ; NG: `"$_POST['name']"`

Comment: Typical, spent about 2hrs trying to solve this before posting and it's a basic error. The included file for the config..wasn't being included. Every comment was valuable though, just wanted to get it working before adding security although the page is only accessible to admins. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not checking the result of the call to `new mysqli`.  If that fails, then `$mysqli` will be null and not a valid object you can query against.

Also, **by building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. My site http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Answer (score 0):

At the setout, you should call

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

This enables you don't have to check any return values, just put `try { ... } catch { ... }` blocks.

```
try {

    if (
        !isset($_POST['name'])     ||
        !is_string($_POST['name']) ||
        $_POST['name'] === ''
    ) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('$_POST[\'name\'] is empty');
    }

    $mysqli = new mysqli($mHost, $mUser, $mPass, $db);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `category` (`name`) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['name']);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo 'Success';

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```